# How to convert an array from row?

Tags: php, arrays

```
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
      echo "<a href='uploads/".$arr['file_name']."'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value=".$arr['document_name']."/></a><input type='checkbox' name='documents' value='Documents'>"; 
}
```

`$arr['document_name'`] returns like `roc, vat, ctc, photoid, addressproof` and there is check box for each document name. my question is how to apply condition for each documents whether it is checked or not.I have an idea to apply but dont know how to apply?? can u pls anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code to the following, it might help.

```
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  echo "<a href='uploads/".$arr['file_name']."'><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value=".$arr['document_name']."/></a><input type='checkbox' name='documents' value=".$arr['document_name'].">"; 
}
```

and to check if it is checked, you can try, (assuming this is submitted via POST method)

```
//Loop each checkbox
foreach($_POST['documents'] AS $check)
{
   if(isset($check)) //Check if the checkbox is checked
   {
     //$check contains the value in $arr['document_name'] for that loop
     echo $check." is checked"; 
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.